# Crear transparencia entre las líneas de un UILabel con Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, layout

Teniendo un *label* de varias líneas y al fondo una imagen. ¿Cómo hacer para que se vea?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3908991/3957845

En esta pregunta hacen referencia a `drawTextInRect` pero tampoco encuentro manera específica de cómo usarlo.

Comment: ¿Cómo hacer para que se vea?.... para que se vea que cosa?, modifica un poco tu pregunta para que sea mas explicita porque ya tiene votos de cierre, si no lo haces la van a cerrar, podrías añadir un poco de tu código fuente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es un tema complejo pero no imposible de conseguir y requiere de bastante código.

La idea es que para que `NSMutableString` detecte los parágrafos el texto debe contener saltos de línea `\n`. Lógicamente, como cada dispositivo tiene un tamaño distinto y el texto no se ajusta igual en cada tamaño de pantalla, necesitamos saber cuantas líneas tiene la `UILabel` y los rangos de cada línea.

Para ello necesitarás esta extensión que he creado para ello:

```
// MARK: - UILabel extension para encontrar cada línea
import CoreText

extension UILabel {

    func everyLineRange(skipN: Bool = false) -> [NSRange]? {

        self.layoutIfNeeded()

        let font: CTFont = CTFontCreateWithName((self.text ?? "") as CFString, self.font.pointSize, nil)

        let mutableString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: self.text ?? "", attributes: [kCTFontAttributeName as String: font])
        let frameSetter: CTFramesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString(mutableString)

        let path = CGMutablePath()
        path.addRect(CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: self.bounds.size.width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))

        let frame = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(frameSetter, CFRangeMake(0, 0), path, nil)
        guard let lines: [CTLine] = CTFrameGetLines(frame) as? [CTLine] else {
            return nil
        }

        var ranges = [NSRange]()
        for l in lines {
            let r = CTLineGetStringRange(l)
            ranges.append(NSMakeRange(r.location, skipN ? r.length - 1 : r.length))
        }

        return ranges

    }

}
```

Una vez tienes los rangos de cada línea, debes hacer algo tal que así:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // 1. El texto
        textLabel.text = "LOREM IPSUM DOLOR SIT, CONSECTETUR\nADIPISCING ELIT. FUSCE VITAE EFFICITUR\nLIGULA. LIGULA, PUR"

        // 2. Ahora necesitamos saber el rango de cada línea teniendo en cuenta los saltos de línea (ver extension UILabel)
        guard let initialRanges = textLabel.everyLineRange() else { return }

        // 3. Para poder realizar el efecto, debemos añadir un salto de línea al texto en función de cada rango (cada línea)
        var stringN = ""
        for r in initialRanges {
            let text = (textLabel.text! as NSString).substring(with: r).trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
            stringN += text + "\n"
        }

        // 4. Asignamos el texto de nuevo
        textLabel.text = stringN

        // 5. Volvemos a sacar los rangos omitiendo los \n (ver extension UILabel)
        guard let ranges = textLabel.everyLineRange(skipN: true) else { return }

        // 6. Añadimos separación a lo parágrafos y el fondo blanco
        let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        paragraphStyle.paragraphSpacing = 5.0

        let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: textLabel.text ?? "", attributes: [NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle])
        for r in ranges {
            attributedText.addAttributes([NSBackgroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white], range: r)
        }

        // 7. Asignamos el texto final
        textLabel.attributedText = attributedText

    }

}
```

Y conseguirás el siguiente efecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias @mhergon es tal cual el efecto que queria. Soy nuevo en Swift 3, quisiera saber si podría ponerme en contacto contigo para aclarar este tipo de dudas algo complejas para mi y algunos consejos de buena practica? Mi correo es chergueta@3dlinkweb.com. Saludos

Comment: Todo lo que sea de programación puedes preguntarlo por aquí. Estaré al tanto para ayudarte. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Basado en la informacion que nos proporcionas, creo que es esto lo que buscas.

De manera programatica, en la funcion *viewDidLoad()* (La cual se inicia con el programa/aplicacion), asignamos de una manera dinamica el texto y el espaciado entre las lineas (5 para el ejemplo).

Espero te ayude.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var label: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let texto = "LOREM IPSUM DOLOR SIT, CONSECTETUR ADIPISCING ELIT. FUSCE VITAE EFFICITUR LIGULA. LIGULA, PUR"

        let atributo = NSMutableAttributedString(string: texto)
        let parrafo = NSMutableParagraphStyle()

        parrafo.lineSpacing = 5 /* Este es el espacio entre lineas */
        atributo.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value: parrafo, range: NSMakeRange(0, atributo.length))

        label.attributedText = atributo

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

}
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta Ivan, efectivamente con ese código creo el espacio entre lineas, pero ese espacio no es transparente por lo que se ve un solo bloque de un solo color.